# how to change the location of a minimized mdichild form?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

In my MDI application i have changed the size of its MDI client to avoid the scrollbars that appear when a portion of an MDI child form is moved out of the view of the client area of the MDI parent form (i made the MDI client size bigger than the size of the screen).

I know i can use an API using [ShowScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to hide these scrollBars but it flickers and i prefere not to use an API.

Now i have a problem that when minimizing any of the MDI child Forms its location is set by default to the bottom of the MDI client (which its size is bigger than the size of the screen) so the minimized MDI child form doesn't appear.

So how can i change the location of a minimized mdichild form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask, why do you want to avoid scrollbars? It's my experience that when I leave the paved roads I'm suddenly faced with more problems than I tried do evade. So I try to live with the standards as much as possible.

Comment: Totally bad idea to hide scroll bars. Cant imagine why you need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the ClientRectangle from the parent and apply the location to the child accordingly before minimizing. I think you ca implement the Form Minimized or minimizing events.